# How to load a binary files of structures into memory

Tags: c, file, struct, malloc, fread

I have a binary file of structures like this:

```
struct sprite{
     char name;
     unsigned int n;
     float coordinates[n][2];
}
```

I have to carry it in memory, (I don't know how many come), so I can use those coordinates.

I have my function that carries these structures into memory, I think this is right, but my problem is that when I want to export to a .txt so I can see if it's well loaded and see what brings this binary file, it doesn't print me properly.

```
bool load_sprites(FILE *f, size_t *n, sprites_t **v){
    size_t alloc_size;
    sprites_t s;
    sprites_t *aux;
    if((*v = malloc(sizeof(sprites_t) * INIT_CHOP)) == NULL)
        return false;
    *n = 0;
    alloc_size = INIT_CHOP;
    while(fread(&s,sizeof(s),1,f)){
        if(*n == alloc_size){
            if((aux = realloc(*v,alloc_size * INIT_CHOP *sizeof(sprites_t)))==NULL){
                free(*v);
                *n=0;
                return false;
            }
            *v = aux;
            alloc_size *= INIT_CHOP;
        }
        memcpy(&(*v)[(*n)++],&s,sizeof(s)); 
    }
    return true;
}
```

My invocation of the function is:

```
load_sprites(f,&n,&ptr):
```

And then, to print this into a .txt i'm using:

```
 for(size_t i = 0; i<n; i++){
  fprintf(fo,"%s ",(ptr+i)->name);
    for(size_t j=0;j<2;j++){
      fprintf(fo,"%.2f  ",ptr->coordinates[i][j]);
    }
    fprintf(fo,"\n\t"); 
}
```

I need this to print me all the content of the file, the object name and their coordinates. It Prints me only the first 3 objects and some coordinates well and others wrong:

```
SHIP -4.00  -6.00  
     4.00  -10.00  
     8.00  14.00  
     0.00  -10.00  
    ST -8.00  -6.00  
     -4.00  229010374656.00  
    ROCK1 0.00  0.00  
     -6.00  -4.00  
     -14.00  0.00  
     -6.00  4.00  
     12799826.00  0.00  
     0.00  0.00  
     0.50  0.50  
     1.00  1.00  
     0.50  0.75  
     0.00  1.00
```

Comment: Your most obvious issue is that the field "name" is a single character, and you seem to want it to be a string (you try to printf it with %s, for example). Second, since the last member of your structure is a variable sized array (which is legal in C), it's size is not counted in the structure size, so you'll need two reads for each structure: one to get fields up to n, and another to read n arrays of floats. It would probably be better to read and write this info as text rather than trying to binary read the structures.

Comment: Your print function is printing the name of object 0, then object 0 coordinate 0, then the name of object 1, then object 0 coordinate 1, then the name of object 2, then object 0 coordinate 2, .... I don't think that's what you wanted it to do.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker You are right with the *Second. First, the "name" it is not a single character, is a string, like "SHIP". Then, you are right, maybe i need to make two reads, because i have the problem to print this structures into a .txt, i tried separately the code and i'm loading well in memory. I going to try that, thanks

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker How can I read the same structure twice? I need somehow to get that n so I can print the coordinates that follow him.

Comment: You don't read the structure twice: one read gets you the size of the structure, then the second read gets the structure itself. You can't know how many bytes to ask for in the second read without doing the first.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Sorry , but I can't understand you. I need to get N's value on some auxiliary variable, then use it when i want to print the coordinates. When you talk about reading, you mean Fread?

Comment: Yes, you read files with fread() (or just read() if you want to go lower-level). But the file system knows nothing about your structures--it's just a dumb bucket of bytes. Since you have a variable-size structure, you have to first read sizeof(int) bytes of the integer that you saved indicating the size, use it to calculate how big the rest of the structure is in bytes, then read that many bytes.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker i understand what you are explaing, but i don't really know how to implement that in my code. So, i made a new post with new information and another code. Because i got confused, the binary file has not structures, it only come with the information, and i need to load all that information into my structures. Maybe is the same that we are talking, but i really don't know how to implement what you are saying to me.